# How to select all but first row in table (ASP.NET GridView) using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, gridview

I need to select all but the first row (header) in all tables (GridView) on an ASP.NET page, so that I can apply the jQuery UI Sortable plugin to those rows so that they can be drag/dropped. If I do this:

```
function pageLoad() {
    $('table > tbody').sortable().disableSelection();
}
```

It correctly applies sortable to the rows in the 'tbody' element and not the header row in the 'thead' element ... until after the first postback, when the 'thead' element is lost and the header row then becomes draggable.

What is the correct way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't you sort values in column?

Comment: The requirement is for users to maintain the ordering (priority) of records in the tables. We do currently have move up/down buttons but this can be cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for the suggestions.

Ended up posting the same question on the jQuery forum. Answer was to specifiy the *items* option on the sortable initialize to select all but the first row:

```
$('table').sortable({items: 'tr:not(:first)'});
```

And this works perfectly ...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all rows but the first you could do:

```
 $('table tr:not(:first)')
```

If you don't have a header row, it skips the first row of the body

Comment: This actually makes the individual row cells draggable within a row (including the header row), so I can swap column cells around, but can't drag & drop the whole row.

Comment: @Marcus actually i don't know how sortable works. I just suggested how to select in jquery all `<tr>` but the first.

Comment: OK, many thanks. Guess I need to check the sortable documentation! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [*gt* selector](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)

and specify the index from which start selecting...

look like  `$('table > tbody > tr:gt(1)').sortable().disableSelection();`

Comment: I think that if you do this you always miss the first row in the tbody which is not what he wants if he has a `<thead>`: maybe `$('table tr:gt(1)').sortable().disableSelection();` is more correct